# UITableviewCell how to setting "ViewHolder"

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, adapter

UITableView with **CustomViewCell** presenting  **local array** data.
**CustomViewCell have button "favorites"** that changes from **SELECTED to UNSELECTED**.

the problem is **while scrolling** down and up, the TableView **Reloads again the Cell with the original button's Status.**

how can it hold cell without reload again?
there is a method to use like java "adapter/viewholder"?

thank you all.

MAIN CLASS:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CommentCell *cellView;


    //    if(cellView == nil)
    //    {
    //        _article            = nil;
    //        cellView.lblAdress  = nil;
    //        cellView.lblName    = nil;
    //        cellView.webImageV  = nil;
    //        cellView.strPhone   = nil;
    //        // cell.btn            = nil;
    //    }


    if (!cellView) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects;

        if([[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"IsMain"]isEqualToString:@"false"])
        {
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }


        if([[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"IsMain"]isEqualToString:@"true"])
        {

            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentCellBIG" owner:self options:nil];

        }

               cellView = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        }





    //    if ([[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"AlreadyFavorite"]isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    //
    //        [cellView.btn setSelected:YES];
    //    }
    //    else if ([[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"AlreadyFavorite"]isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
    //        [cellView.btn setSelected:NO];
    //    }



    _article = [articles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cellView setArticle:_article];


    return cellView;

}
```

loads Cells Data:

```
-(void)loadArticle
{
    [articles removeAllObjects];

    for (int i =0; i<[arrResultsALL count]; i++)
    {
        _article = [[Comment alloc]initWithName:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]
                                         Adress:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"address"]
                                       ImageURL:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"logo"]
                                          ObjID:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]
                                          Phone:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"phone"]
                                      Favorites:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"AlreadyFavorite"]
                                         IsMain:[[arrResultsALL objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"IsMain"]

                    ];



        [articles addObject:_article];
    }

}
```

**

> CustomCell class:

**

```
-(void)setArticle:(Comment*)_article {

    self.webImageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AdPictureFrame"];

    if (!StringIsNilOrEmpty(_article.ImageURL)) {
        NSURL *animationUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:_article.ImageURL];
        if (!StringIsNilOrEmpty(animationUrl.pathExtension)) {
            self.webImageV.image = nil;
            [self.webImageV loadFromURL:animationUrl];
        }
    }


    self.strAlreadyFavorites=_article.AlreadyFavorites;
    self.strIsMain = _article.IsMain;


    NSLog(@"strAlreadyFavoritesstrAlreadyFavorites=%@",strAlreadyFavorites);

    if ([strAlreadyFavorites isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        [self.btn setSelected:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.btn setSelected:NO];
    }



    self.ObjectID       =_article.ObjID;
    self.lblName.text   =_article.Name;
    self.lblAdress.text =_article.Adress;
    strPhone            =_article.Phone;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better familiarize yourself with the concept of reusing cells.

The delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called every time when a cell is supposed to become visible in the table. When the user scrolls up and down then it is called several times for what you (and the user) think(s) may be the same cell.

Every time when a cell is scrolled off screen then it is moved to the pool of reusable cells.

So first, fetch a cell from the reuse-pool. Only if you don't get one (and depending on how you actually fetch it that may or may never be the case) create a new instance of your cell.

You, on the contrary, always create a new cell! 
(If I am not much mistaken, you are waisting memory here even with ARC. You may not if your cell does not have a reuse-ID, because then it is not moved to the reusage-pool.)

Once you have your cell bare in mind that the method may be called for a cell that -from the user's point of view- was visible earlier and may have a selection state or other data on it. That means for you: When ever the user changes something to a cell that you want to recover after scrolling up and down or vice versa, then you need to store that status somewhere ex the cell object. And you need to restore the view respectively in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Currently you don't do anything alike.

Comment: you have Example URL?
or can Guide me what exactly definition to search of that?

Comment: Of course. It is explained in here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html and detailled documented in here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html